# Python Tkinter Increment (to have default value zero)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a program using python tkinter. I want to increment or decrement the entry box whenever I click button. It works fine for my codes. The only problem is whenever I want to refresh or pressed another button for  the increment to go back to zero? How can I do that? I tried to delete the entrybox but it got an error. Thank you

Below is just snippets of my code since it is lengthy. Thank you

```
global number1, number2, number3, number4, number5, number6, number7, new_price
    new_price = []
    number1= IntVar()
    number2 = IntVar()
    number3 = IntVar()
    number4 = IntVar()
    number5 = IntVar()
    number6 = IntVar()
    number7 = IntVar()

self.entry2 = Entry(classic_milk, textvariable=number2, justify="center")
    self.entry2.place(relx=0.448, rely=0.738, width=25, height=15)
    self.entry2.configure(font="-family {Poppins} -size 10")
    self.entry2.configure(relief="flat")
    self.entry2.configure(bg="#dadada")
    #self.entry2.insert(0, textentry)

    self.entry3 = Entry(classic_milk, textvariable=number3, justify="center")
    self.entry3.place(relx=0.448, rely=0.775, width=25, height=15)
    self.entry3.configure(font="-family {Poppins} -size 10")
    self.entry3.configure(relief="flat")
    self.entry3.configure(bg="#dadada")
    #self.entry3.insert(0, textentry)

def add1(self):
    number1.set(number1.get() + 1)

def add2(self):
    number2.set(number2.get() + 1)

def add3(self):
    number3.set(number3.get() + 1)

def add4(self):
    number4.set(number4.get() + 1)

def add5(self):
    number5.set(number5.get() + 1)

def add6(self):
    number6.set(number6.get() + 1)

def add7(self):
    number7.set(number7.get() + 1)

def minus1(self):
    if number1.get() > 0:
        number1.set(number1.get() - 1)

def minus2(self):
    if number2.get() > 0:
        number2.set(number2.get() - 1)

def minus3(self):
    if number3.get() > 0:
        number3.set(number3.get() - 1)

def minus4(self):
    if number4.get() > 0:
        number4.set(number4.get() - 1)

def minus5(self):
    if number5.get() > 0:
        number5.set(number5.get() - 1)

def minus6(self):
    if number6.get() > 0:
        number6.set(number6.get() - 1)

def minus7(self):
    if number7.get() > 0:
        number7.set(number7.get() - 1)
```

Comment: What error you got when you tried to reset the entry boxes? `numberX.set(0)` does not work?